# Timestamp not updated on reactor Mono.defer invocation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, reactive-programming, project-reactor

I have a service which gives a list of exchange rates for all present stock symbols in the database.
The invocation is very simple, when the `rates()` method of the service is called, a random rate is given in the form of the following class:

```
public class Rate {
  private final long timestamp = Instant.now().toEpochMilli();
  private String symbol;
  private final double rate = (Math.random() * 100).toBigDecimal().setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP).doubleValue();

  // getters and setters
}
```

The service method implementation is:

```
public Flux<Rate> rates() {
  return service.findAll();
}
```

I have a reactive WebSocketHandler that looks like this:

```
@Service
public class MyHandler implements WebSocketHandler {

    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;
    private final RateService service;
    private final ApplicationProperties applicationProperties;

    public MyHandler(ObjectMapper objectMapper, RateService service, ApplicationProperties applicationProperties) {
        this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
        this.service = service;
        this.applicationProperties = applicationProperties;
    }

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> handle(WebSocketSession session) {
        return session.send(
                Mono.defer(() -> service.rates().collectList())
                        .repeat()
                        .delayElements(Duration.ofSeconds(applicationProperties.getInterval()))
                        .map(value -> {
                            try {
                                return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(value);
                            } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                                return null;
                            }
                        })
                        .map(session::textMessage)
        );
    }
}
```

When I connect to the WebSocket via a client I get a list of rates every 5 seconds which is good. The only problem I have is that the `timestamp` property is the exact same time stamp every 5 seconds. So my first response through the WebSocket is like this: `[{"timestamp":"2018-10-08T09:52:51.387Z","symbol":"GOOG","rate":33.91}]` and the second response is `[{"timestamp":"2018-10-08T09:52:51.387Z","symbol":"GOOG","rate":51.43}]`. So the rate HAS changed but the timestamp hasn't.

I CAN solve it however by overriding the getter of the `rate` field but I was hoping not to solve it in that layer. I just want the getter to return the value without manipulating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nearly correct, to understand please run the following below, there are a few things that were in the wrong place, I suggest you start by looking at the timestamps emitted with `'Creating Rate'`.

Before you were creating the List and repeat and repeat and repeat, so this was being created and stored before sending it to the client, so if you delay the creation process rather than the sending process, the Rates will be created every 5 seconds and emitted.

```
public class MyHandler  {

    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    public Flux<String> handle() {
        return Mono.defer(() -> rates().delayElements(Duration.ofSeconds(5)).collectList())
                .repeat()
                .map(value -> {
                    try {
                        return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(value);
                    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                        return null;
                    }
                });
    }

    private Flux<Rate> rates() {
        return Flux.just(new Rate("a"), new Rate("b"), new Rate("c"));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MyHandler().handle()
                .subscribe(str -> System.out.println(str + ", time now - " + Instant.now().toEpochMilli()));
        try {
            Thread.sleep(60_000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    static class Rate {
        private final long timestamp;
        private String symbol;
        private final double rate;

        public Rate(String symbol) {
            this.symbol = symbol;
            timestamp = Instant.now().toEpochMilli();
            rate  = new BigDecimal(Math.random() * 100).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP).doubleValue();
            System.out.println("Creating Rate " + timestamp);
        }
        // getters and setters

        public long getTimestamp() {
            return timestamp;
        }
        public String getSymbol() {
            return symbol;
        }
        public void setSymbol(String symbol) {
            this.symbol = symbol;
        }
        public double getRate() {
            return rate;
        }
    }
}
```